# How to model state change timeline

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I've got an app where users can place orders for recurring delivery of a particular service.

The `orders` table has columns `service_id` and `state`, where `service_id` links to the service the user has ordered and `state` can be `active` or `inactive`, reflecting whether the user currently wants to receive that service or not. Users can toggle orders on and off as they please.

When a user turns an order on or off (active/inactive) I need to track this, and I need to be able to query for whether an order was active or inactive on a given date.

**My question is: What's the best way to to model something like this, specifically so that I can easily write a query like "all orders that were active on (date)"?**

I've thought about making a `orders_states` table with `order_id`, `state`, and `date`, where each change create a row with the state that was set and the date it was set, but I'm not 100% sure about how I'd query it to get the past state on an arbitrary date, or if there's a better way to model this.

I'm testing / prototyping on this now, but I'm obviously not a SQL expert and would love some suggestions from the pros here. Thanks!

*(I'm using Postgres 9.4.1.2 in case that matters, but I figure this is more of a generic SQL modeling question)*

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'll need an order state table. You can create a new row every time the state changes for an order (how you do this is up to you: triggers, SP or on the application layer). That table must have a non-null timestamp column to get the time the row was created.